# Power BI and Visual studio requiring 2 different versions of Microsoft Access Database Engine

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access, powerbi

I've created an app in Visual Studio that utilities the 32 bit version of Microsoft Access Database Engine to store data in an Access database. I've been collecting data for a while now and downloaded Power BI to create some interesting visualisations.

In order to connect my database to Power BI, I need to have the 64 bit version of Microsoft Access Database Engine. I uninstalled the 32 bit version but obviously have the opposite problem now.

From what I've read it doesn't look like there's an easy answer to this, has anyone else dealt with this problem?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Compile 64-bit version of your program.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov - yep, that's the answer! Probably should have thought of this myself! Thanks for answering